# Determining how many functions are declared at the global scope

Tags: javascript, function, internet-explorer, scope

Is there any way to determine how many or what functions are defined at certain scope?, let's say the global scope...

I don't think so, but I give it a try here

**EDIT:** looping through window properties does not work in IE for this purpose. Is it doable in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to inspect a `window` object, which represent global scope. Use for example `for (var in obj) {}`

Comment: I'm accepting this one since it's the right thing to do in most scenarios and modern browsers now in 2012, although it was not working by the time it was tested under IE7.

Answer (score 0):

Look through the `window` object:

```
for (var p in window)
{
  console.log(window[p]);
}
```

Any function you create becomes method of the `window` object, so you need to inspect that to see what is in the global scope.

Comment: Just note that in all IE versions, identifiers defined with a Function Declaration or a Variable Declaration on the Global Execution Context, will not be enumerated in the `for-in` loop. This is a well known bug and hasn't been fixed even on IE9pre3. Check this [example](http://jsbin.com/aboge4/2/edit).

Comment: @CMS: That very bad then, hope there is a workaround for that. Thanks

Comment: I already tried that whithout any success, I forgot to mention that I was testing in IE. Thanks Anyway